# Which front end technology is GMail using?

Tags: javascript, frameworks

We where evaluating javascript frameworks, and i was pointed out that Google, altough promoting the development of angular, is not using it in GMail.

But what is actually being used in GMail, if a javascript framework used at all? It is one of the best front end applications around, so this is interesting to know. The client side logic looks quite rich, also.

I googled around but i didn't find anything.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I'm aware the bulk of the code that drives GMail is Google's Closure library: 
http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2009/11/introducing-closure-tools.html

Answer (score 7):

It uses Google's closure library. It is explicitly stated here.
https://code.google.com/p/closure-library/

Answer (score 4):

Google's Closure Library [latest link]:

https://developers.google.com/closure/library/